# Checking character arrays - returns same answer each time

Tags: c++, arrays, char

So I've been programming for an assignment -- I am supposed to create a program that asks for the number of questions, the correct answers, and the answers provided to score the test.In the program I wrote, I always get the same return value for the score: 4199676

Can anyone tell me why I get this return value? Many thanks.

```
int main(){
int qnum = 1;
int counter;
int corr_counter;
char correct[10000];
char answer[10000];
while(qnum != 0){
    cout<<"Enter the number of questions on the test (0 to exit).\n";
    cin>>qnum;
    while(qnum < 0){
        cout<<"Please enter a valid number of questions.\n";
        cin>>qnum;
    }
    for(counter = 0; counter < qnum; counter++){
        cout<<"Enter the correct answer for question "<<counter<<". The answer can be A, B, C, D, or E.\n";
        cin>>correct[counter];
        toupper(correct[counter]);
        while(correct[counter] != 'A' && correct[counter] != 'B' && correct[counter] != 'C' && correct[counter] != 'D' && correct[counter] != 'E'){
            cout<<"Please enter either A, B, C, D, or E.\n";
            cin>>correct[counter];
            toupper(correct[counter]);
        }
    }
    for(counter = 0; counter < qnum; counter++){
        cout<<"Enter the student's answer for question "<<counter<<". The answer can be A, B, C, D, or E.\n";
        cin>>answer[counter];
        toupper(answer[counter]);
        while(answer[counter] != 'A' && answer[counter] != 'B' && answer[counter] != 'C' && answer[counter] != 'D' && answer[counter] != 'E'){
            cout<<"Please enter either A, B, C, D, or E.\n";
            cin>>answer[counter];
            toupper(answer[counter]);
        }
    }
    for(counter = 0; counter < qnum; counter++){
        if(answer[counter] == correct[counter]){
            corr_counter++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"Score: "<<corr_counter<<"\n";
    return(0);
}
```

}

Comment: You did not initialize `corr_counter`, so the variable appears to have whatever value is at the given memory location. Just initialize it to `0` and you're fine.

Comment: But this goes to why "not debugging" is a reason for closure of a question.  If you debugged your code, you should have seen the problem right away.  Next time, please debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialised `corr_counter`.

You declare it at the top but you never initialised it to 0, which is what you meant to do. You are thus incrementing from an unknown start point.